# Nvoglv32.pdb not loaded OpenGL issue in visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opengl, glut

When I try to run my code for a scrolling text banner in visual studio, it gives me this exception:

[image: Exception]

The text starts scrolling from right to left. When the first letter touches the left border, it should change its basepoint, but now it gives this exception. Someone who knows how to solve this, that the text keeps scrolling, and starts again and again.

I tried to put an extern nvoglv32.pdb downloaded file in my visual studio appdata, but without success.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>

#ifdef WIN32
#include <windows.h>
#endif
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
using namespace std;

//static int font_index = 0;
int state = 1;
float xsize = 600;
float ysize = 300;


void print_bitmap_string(/*void* font,*/ const char* s)
{

    while (*s) {
        glutBitmapCharacter(GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_24, *s);
        s++;
    }
}

void reshape(int w, int h)
{
    GLdouble size;
    GLdouble aspect;

    /* Use the whole window. */
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);

    /* We are going to do some 2-D orthographic drawing. */
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    size = (GLdouble)((w >= h) ? w : h) / 2.0;
    if (w <= h) {
        aspect = (GLdouble)h / (GLdouble)w;
        glOrtho(-size, size, -size * aspect, size * aspect, -100000.0, 100000.0);
    }
    else {
        aspect = (GLdouble)w / (GLdouble)h;
        glOrtho(-size * aspect, size * aspect, -size, size, -100000.0, 100000.0);
    }

    /* Make the world and window coordinates coincide so that 1.0 in */
    /* model space equals one pixel in window space.                 */
    glScaled(aspect, aspect, 1.0);

    /* Now determine where to draw things. */
    //glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    //glLoadIdentity();
}

float x_pos = xsize / 2;
float y_pos = 70;
float x_offset = 0.0;
size_t Size = 0;
float sizetext=0;
const char* bitmap_font_names = "Testing train";
const char* bitmap_font_names2 = "Deze trein heeft bestemmingen: Oostende, Brugge, Gent-Sint-Pieters, Gent-Dampoort, Lokeren, Sint-Niklaas, Beveren(Waas), Antwerpen-Berchem, Antwerpen-Centraal";

void draw()
{
    
    Size = strlen(bitmap_font_names);
    sizetext = Size * 11;
    //cout << sizetext << endl;

    glPushMatrix();
    /* Draw the strings, according to the current mode and font. */
    glTranslatef(0.5, -100, 0);
    //set the text color
    glColor4f(0.0f, 173.0f, 115.0f, 1.0f);

    glRasterPos2f(x_pos+x_offset, y_pos /* + 1.25 * yild*/);
    if (x_pos < -xsize/2) {
        glBitmap(xsize, ysize, 0.0, 0.0, -xsize, 0.0, NULL); 
        x_offset = xsize;
    }
    if (sizetext > xsize) {
        for (int i = -3; i > -500; i -= 2) {
            if (x_pos < i * xsize / 2) {
                glBitmap(xsize, ysize, 0.0, 0.0, -xsize, 0.0, NULL);
                x_offset += xsize;
            }
        }

    }
    print_bitmap_string(bitmap_font_names);
    glPopMatrix();
}

void display(void)
{
    //change background color
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    draw();

    glColor3f(0.0, 255.0, 0.0);
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);

    glVertex2f(sizetext + x_pos, y_pos);
    glVertex2f(x_pos, 0 + y_pos);
    glVertex2f(x_pos, 20 + y_pos);
    glVertex2f(sizetext + x_pos, 20 + y_pos);

    glEnd();

    glutSwapBuffers();
}


void timer(int) {
    glutPostRedisplay();
    glutTimerFunc(1000 / 1000, timer, 0);
    switch (state) {
    case 1:
        if (x_pos > (-xsize / 2) -sizetext) {
            x_pos -= 1;
        }
        else {
            state = -1;
        }
        break;
    case -1:
        x_pos = (xsize / 2);
        x_offset = 0;
        state = 1;
        break;
    }

    //cout << x_pos << endl;
}


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    glutInitWindowSize(xsize, ysize);
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DOUBLE);
    glutCreateWindow("Train Display");
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
    glutTimerFunc(1000, timer, 0);
    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: pdb not loaded has nothing to do with your program throwing exceptions. It just means it will be more difficult for you to debug inside the dll that goes with this file. Do you want to debug your GPU drivers? I think you can break out  of that dialog and switch the stack frame to your code.

Comment: I see that you did not add the nVidia symbol server: [https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-driver-symbol-server](https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-driver-symbol-server)

Comment: I don't want to debug my GPU drivers. When I start the program it just crashes, but a month ago, it worked. That's what I don't understand.

Comment: You can try my second comment to install the correct pdb. That won't fix your issue at all but it will get rid of the annoying Visual Studio window. In either case I believe you can exit that window and use the "Stack Frame" on the debug toolbar to switch to your code to see what line of your code was running when your program caused your GPU driver to crash. I would say this is still more likely a bug in your code and not a bug in nVidia's driver. It could have been undefined behavior in your code that now causes the code to crash when it did not in the past.

Comment: Yes, I did that. But it stil gives the same error/exception.

Comment: ***But it stil gives the same error/exception.*** It is expected that you will still get the exception. You have to debug your bug in your code.  Having the .pdb will not fix any bug or stop an exception from happening.

Comment: Okay, I will try and find the bug. Thanks for your respons.